# Magento Using all attributes within layered nav

Tags: php, mysql, magento, layered-navigation

I currently have a load of attributes already setup as text boxes - is there anyway I can get them appearing within the layered nav?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Regards

Shane

Comment: How do you want them to appear in the layered nav? As other options do, with links to filter down? As search boxes? Please elaborate on what you intend here.

Comment: as the other options do , or possibly one step further - is it possible to have checkboxes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right for anybody else looking at this, I looked into going down the custom code route, but quickly back tracked...

I decieded to bit the bullet, delete my attributes and recreate them and import the products again.

Answer (score 1):

Given what you are looking for, Magento does not support what you want by default. However, the Magento filter code is fairly well structured, so this is something that you could add at will. The relevant backend code that will need to be modified is in the Catalog/Model/Layer subdirectory. Specifically, you will need to edit `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer` to accommodate your new code. Also, you'll need to add a class that implements `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Abstract`, to handle the actual filtering code. Finally, you will need to make the options appear on the frontend, which (in my cursory examination) will require two major changes. Firstly, you'll need to change the backend to allow the admin to mark text fields as being filterable, after which you'll need to modify the frontend template to display the checkbox fields.

This is a really significant amount of work. If at all possible, I'd recommend avoiding this route as it will also probably cause you significant problems down the road.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Hi Joseph, Thanks for the answer, I really appreciate it! I had a horrible feeling that Magneto didn't do it by default, so I'll wait for a couple of days to see if anyone has actually developed something similar, I can't believe that more people require this! If nobody else answers then I'll give it a bash at writing the code and give you full marks! Thanks again Shane